# Add div in last of the list but I am getting error in design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below my div content list
I want to add same type of div having class (commentClass) with different content at the last of commentClass div

```
<div style="padding-top: 12px;" class="col-md-10 commentClass">
                            <div class="col-md-1"><img class="circle" src="../upload/default.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-11">
                                <p><label>@test22222 </label>The lipstick I have been looking for! Usually lip products dry me out, this one did not even without prior mosturizing! Anna is a great nude shade, color stays in place even </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div style="padding-top: 12px;" class="col-md-10 commentClass">
                            <div class="col-md-1"><img class="circle" src="../upload/736988_10151398960426369_650127657_o.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-11">
                                <p><label>gfdg </label>I've had several Nars lipsticks, and would definitely say that the Audacious line is the best.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div style="padding-top: 12px;" class="col-md-10 commentClass">
                            <div class="col-md-1"><img class="circle" src="../upload/default.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-11">
                                <p><label>@test </label>Hello guys, previously we have posted a good script to export data from MySQL to CSV File, today we will share another script which would export data from MySQL to excel file.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<div id="commentArea" class="col-md-10" style="padding-top: 12px;">
                            <div class="col-md-1" style="z-index: 1;"><img src="../upload/test333_819.jpg" class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-11">
                                <textarea id="textComment" class="comment-box"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I tried jquery prepend of id="commentArea" but did not work 
commentArea

```
var commentstring ='<div style="padding-top: 12px;" class="col-md-10 commentClass">test content</div>';

$( "#commentArea" ).prepend( commentstring );
```

Comment: If you want to add it last i think you should be using `append` instead of `prepend`. Also, show `#commentArea` and format your HTML.

Comment: I tried with $(".commentClass:last").html(commentstring); but did not work

Comment: Look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/46pwLxmq/ Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes its working .. $("#commentArea").before(commentstring); this is also working same as you describe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it may work for you

```
var commentstring ='<div style="padding-top: 12px;" class="col-md-10 commentClass">test content</div>';

$("#commentArea").before(commentstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

your .prepend() method will also work just check the version of jQuery you are using.
 this works for me.

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){
   $('#bclass').prepend('<div>Hello I was added</div>') ;
  });
});
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/duregu/edit?html,js,console,output)